# how to read excel's data to json string?

Tags: excel

I have a excel like this:

A       B       C

a1     b1      c1
                   c2
a2     b2      c3
                   c4

Now i want to read the data to json string using c# language like this:
"{'a1':{'b1':['c1','c2']},'a2':{'b2':['c3','c4']}}"

I want to do it because i have to to parse this data to json in javascript,
the data i want to have is:

```
var obj = {
a1:{
    b1:[c1,c2]
},
a2:{
    b2:[c3,c4]
}}
```

I have thought,but i have no thinking.

part of my c# code is this:

```
public string SheetToData(Worksheet worksheet)
        {
            int rowsCount = worksheet.NotEmptyRowMax;
            int columnsCount = worksheet.NotEmptyColumnMax;
            if (rowsCount < 1 || columnsCount < 1)
            {
                return;
            }

            for (int r = 0; r < rowsCount + 1; r++)
            {
                var row = worksheet.Rows[r];
                for (int c = 0; c < columnsCount + 1; c++)
                {
                    var cell = row[c];
                    var value = (cell.ValueAsString ?? "").Trim();

                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your help who can help me solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

The *row* variable is not needed. You can access a cell value through Cells collection:

```
for (int r = 0; r < rowsCount + 1; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < columnsCount + 1; c++)
    {
        var value = (worksheet.Cells[r,c].Value ?? "").ToString().Trim();
    }
}
```